# line-by-line reading of file with stray \r characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm processing text files generated by someone else.  These files have lines separated by the 0xA character, however occasional lines have 0xD thrown in them.  Here's how I read the file:

```
for i, line in enumerate(open(file_path, "r", newline=chr(10))):
   ...
```

it appears, even those I tell `open` to use 0xA as a line separator, it still gets confused by stray 0xDs that cause it to parse an incomplete line.  What am I missing?

(processing is happening on Windows)

Comment: Are you trying to get the old 'universal newline' support or do you want the LFs to be the online newline? How are you testing that the parsing is 'incomplete'?

Comment: I can see that for records that have ^M mixed within, `line` stops at `^M` and then the next iteration through the for-loop, `line` starts right after `^M`

Comment: Can you post the code and some sample data? 'I can see' is not something anyone else can try.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work as expected here (Python 3.5):

```
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'wb') # write in binary mode so nothing is changed
>>> f.write('both\r\nnewline\ncarriagereturn\rbothagain\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
40    
>>> f.close()

>>> open('test.txt', 'rb').read() # confirm data is intact
>>> b'both\r\nnewline\ncarriagereturn\rbothagain\r\n'

>>> list(open('test.txt', 'r', newline=None)) # universal mode (convert everything to '\n')
['both\n', 'newline\n', 'carriagereturn\n', 'bothagain\n']

>>> list(open('test.txt', 'r', newline='')) # universal mode but leave data unchanged
['both\r\n', 'newline\n', 'carriagereturn\r', 'bothagain\r\n']

>>> list(open('test.txt', 'r', newline='\n')) # split only on '\n'
['both\r\n', 'newline\n', 'carriagereturn\rbothagain\r\n']

>>> list(open('test.txt', 'r', newline='\r')) # split only on '\r'
['both\r', '\nnewline\ncarriagereturn\r', 'bothagain\r', '\n']

>>> list(open('test.txt', 'r', newline='\r\n')) # split only on '\r\n'
['both\r\n', 'newline\ncarriagereturn\rbothagain\r\n']
```

Could you post some sample data & code for verification?

Answer (score 0):

Can you manually do a split line?

```
for i, line in enumerate(open(file_path, "r").read().split('\n')):
    ...
```

Comment: I am not soliciting workarounds.  I want to understand why my code isn't working.

Comment: In that case, one possibility could be that the file is created on a different platform (non Windows), and your Python is built without universal newline support for some reason (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines)